# Plotly subplots - legend item next to its plot

Tags: python, r, ggplot2, plotly, legend

When using `plotly` subplots, here's a typical example (from https://plotly.com/python/subplots/):

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = make_subplots(rows=3, cols=1)
fig.append_trace(go.Scatter(x=[3, 4, 5], y=[1000, 1100, 1200]), row=1, col=1)
fig.append_trace(go.Scatter(x=[2, 3, 4], y=[100, 110, 120]), row=2, col=1)
fig.append_trace(go.Scatter(x=[0, 1, 2], y=[10, 11, 12]), row=3, col=1)
fig.update_layout(height=600, width=600, title_text="Stacked Subplots")
fig.show()
```

[image]

This doesn't look too bad with just 3 data series, but when I have e.g. 5 subplots that each have a few series, it gets quite difficult to visually associate an item in the legend with where it appears in a plot.

**Is it possible to move the legend items downward to align them with the plots in which they appear?**

Incidentally, I'm actually working in R, not Python, and I'm generating a list of the individual plots using `ggplot` and `ggplotly()`, then assembling them like so:

```
  p <- subplot(plots, shareX=TRUE, nrows=length(plots))
  layout_args <- c(list(p,
                        title=title,
                        xaxis=list(title = 'Time (Local)'),
                        legend=list(orientation = 'v')),
                   yaxis_args)
  p <- do.call(layout, layout_args)
  htmlwidgets::saveWidget(htmlwidgets::as_widget(p), outfile)
```

But I'm guessing a solution will probably apply equally to both R and Python.

Comment: Probably need to use annotations instead of an automatic legend.  Would this be an acceptable workaround for you?  BTW probably easiest to do this sort of thing directly in plotly API rather than via ggploty

Comment: @dww by annotations do you mean markings on the plot itself rather than a legend on the side?  I don't think that would be great in my case, because you'd lose the ability to use them as a toggle on/off for the trace.

Comment: User `jrmisty` at https://community.plotly.com/t/plotly-subplots-with-individual-legends/1754/18 seems to have worked up a partial solution, though unfortunately the toggling behavior there is to toggle *all* of the traces for a single plot as a group.  So close...

Comment: @KenWilliams - this can easily be accomplished using the groupclick attribute as in `layout(legend=list(tracegroupgap=150, groupclick="toggleitem"))`

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways, IMHO simplest is to add additional scatter traces that have text label of line. **x** and **y** of text scatter are line x/y of traces

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = make_subplots(rows=3, cols=1)
fig.append_trace(go.Scatter(x=[3, 4, 5], y=[1000, 1100, 1200]), row=1, col=1)
fig.append_trace(go.Scatter(x=[2, 3, 4], y=[100, 110, 120]), row=2, col=1)
fig.append_trace(go.Scatter(x=[0, 1, 2], y=[10, 11, 12]), row=3, col=1)
fig.append_trace(go.Scatter(mode="text", text=["trace 1"], x=[5], y=[1200]), row=1, col=1)
fig.append_trace(go.Scatter(mode="text", text=["trace 2"],x=[4], y=[120]), row=2, col=1)
fig.append_trace(go.Scatter(mode="text", text=["trace 3"],x=[2], y=[12]), row=3, col=1)

fig.update_layout(height=600, width=600, title_text="Stacked Subplots", showlegend=False)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Rob - the drawback of this approach is that you can't use the legend anymore as a toggle on/off for the trace.  With the number of traces in my plots that's an important feature.

Comment: agreed - the other answer is an approach that I've experimented with and found more "awkward".  An option you could do is still show the legend in top right, plus labels on lines as I have presented.  Then you can toggle traces and also know what a line is...

Answer (score 2):

Since you stated that you need to have an interactive legend in which traces can be toggled on and off, it won't be possible to just use annotations on the subplots.

Its a bit of a messy workaround, but, to achieve this you can try using `tracegroupgap`. The downside is that you will need to tinker with the value you supply to this option to match the size of the window.

```
p1 = plot_ly(data.frame(x=c(3, 4, 5), y=c(1000, 1100, 1200))) %>%
       add_lines(~x, ~y, legendgroup = 'group1', name = 'Trace 1')
p2 = plot_ly(data.frame(x=c(3, 4, 5), y=c(1000, 1100, 1200))) %>%
       add_lines(~x, ~y, legendgroup = 'group2', name = 'Trace 2')
p3 = plot_ly(data.frame(x=c(3, 4, 5), y=c(1000, 1100, 1200))) %>%
       add_lines(~x, ~y, legendgroup = 'group3', name = 'Trace 3')
subplot(p1,p2,p3,nrows = 3, shareX = TRUE) %>%
  layout(legend=list(tracegroupgap=150))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I think this would be a good way to deal with it.  Is there some way to apply `legendgroup` to existing plot objects created with `ggplotly()`?

Comment: Note that if you add the groupclick attribute as in `layout(legend=list(tracegroupgap=150, groupclick="toggleitem"))`, you can select and deselect individual traces of a group instead of all or nothing.